# Find the expectation of a complex random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, complex-integration

Assume Z is a standard complex normally distributed random variable(i.e. $ Z \sim N_{C}(0,1) $).How to calculate the expectation of $ Z^k\cdot\bar{Z^l} $(i.e. $ E[Z^k\cdot\bar{Z^l}] $)where $ \bar{Z} $ is the conjugate of $Z$.
I think I have to calculate a complex integral by making use of polar transformation.However,I still find it difficult.

Comment: The first 6 of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals#Definite_integrals_lacking_closed-form_antiderivatives) are integrals involving $\Gamma$ function. See if you can find terms that look like that.

Comment: Consider the cases $k=l$ and $k\ne l$ separately.